# Whey Protein Digestion rate? Am I wasting my protein?

Tags: whey

According to this site:

http://www.precisionnutrition.com/rr-whey-too-much

When we take take protein shake in liquid form, it has only 1.5 hours to absorb and absorption rate is 8-10 g per hour. So in 1.5 hours maximum protein absorbed is 15 grams. They also said increase in amino acids level is 30%(without enzymes) vs 110%(with enzymes).

I can only eat 3-4 meals per day.Example my morning meal - I drink 50-60 grams of whey with oats(around 60 grams of protein).It means only 15 grams is absorbed and 45 grams is wasted(or used as energy).Should i consider taking enzymes??

Answer (score 1):

*No*. That article has absolutely no credible references for those numbers. Your body most certainly does not absorb at most 10g of protein per hour. Depending on muscle fiber breakdown, absorption of protein can be much higher. Note, however, that even if *your* absorption limit is 10g/hour, your body will continue using protein for many hours post workout. In fact, a lot of repair continues on to the next day.